# Order of std::mutex locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, stdthread

I’ve rarely thought about what happens between two consecutive expressions, between the call to a function and the execution of its body's first expression, or between a call to a constructor and the execution of its initializer. Then I started reading about concurrency...

1.) In two consecutive calls to `std::thread`’s constructor with the same callable (e.g. function, functor, lambda), whose body begins with a `std::lock_guard` initialization with the same `std::mutex` object, does the standard guarantee the thread corresponding to the first `thread` constructor call executes the lock-protected code first?

2.) If the standard doesn’t make the guarantee, then is there any theoretical or practical possibility the thread corresponding to the second `thread` constructor call executes the protected code first? (e.g. heavy system load during the execution of the initializer or body of the first `thread` constructor call)

Here’s a global `std::mutex` object `m` and a global `unsigned` `num` initialized to `1`. There is nothing but whitespace between function `foo`’s body’s opening brace `{` and the `std::lock_guard`. In `main`, there are two `std::thread`s `t1` and `t2`. `t1` calls the thread constructor first. `t2` calls the thread constructor second. Each thread is constructed with a pointer to `foo`. `t1` calls `foo` with `unsigned` argument `1`. `t2` calls `foo` with `unsigned` argument `2`. Depending on which thread locks the `mutex` first, `num`’s value will be either a `4` or a `3` after both threads have executed the lock-protected code. `num` will equal `4` if `t1` beats `t2` to the lock. Otherwise, `num` will equal `3`. I ran 100,000 trials of this by looping and resetting `num` to `1` at the end of each loop. (As far as I know, the results don’t and shouldn’t depend on which thread is `join()`ed first.)

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex m;
unsigned short num = 1;

void foo(unsigned short par) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
    if (1 == num)
        num += par;
    else
        num *= par;
}

int main() {
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        std::thread t1(foo, 1);
        std::thread t2(foo, 2);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        if (4 == num) {
            ++count;
        }
        num = 1;
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

In the end, `count` equals `100000`, so it turns out `t1` wins the race every time. But these trials don’t prove anything.

3.) Does the standard mandate “first to call `thread` constructor” always implies “first to call the callable passed to the `thread` constructor”?

4.) Does the standard mandate “first to call the callable passed to the `thread` constructor” always implies “first to lock the `mutex`”; provided that within the callable’s body, there exists no code dependent upon the parameter(s) passed to the callable prior to the line with the `std::lock_guard` initialization? (Also rule out any callable’s local `static` variable, like a counter of number of times called, which can be used to intentionally delay certain calls.)

Comment: No, yes, unclear, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, the standard doesn't guarantee that the first thread gets the lock first. Basically, if you need to impose and ordering between threads, you'll need to synchronize between these threads. Even if the first thread gets to call the mutex lock function first, the second thread may acquire the lock first.
2. Absolutely. For example, there may be just one core available to your application at the time the threads are spawned and if the spawning thread decides after the second thread is spawned to wait on something, the schedule may decide to process the latest thread seen which is the second thread. Even if there are many cores available there are plenty of reasons the second thread is faster.
3. No, why would it! The first step is to spawn a thread and carry on. By the time the first function object is called the second thread can be running and call its function object.
4. No. There are not ordering guarantees between threads unless you explicitly impose them yourself as they would defeat the purpose of concurrency.